# unable to get result from MySql Stored Procedure/Function to JPQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

This is my Code of Stored Function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func`()
    RETURNS int(11)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0;
select count(*) INTO total from students;
RETURN total;
END
```

Java Code:

```
query=em.createNativeQuery("{ SELECT func() }");  
        String s=(String) query.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println(s);
```

But ir gives an Exception:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ SELECT func() }' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: { SELECT func() }
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="{ SELECT func() }")
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ SELECT func() }' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: { SELECT func() }
Query: DataReadQuery(sql="{ SELECT func() }")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
    at org.ceynamon.oregano.datamigration.Test.main(Test.java:26)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces around `SELECT funct()` are not needed